# Imported maven project but can't see jsp in WEB-INF in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, import, war

I checked out a maven project, the directory looks like this :

```
.settings
[bin]
```

[src] inside this folder there is [java],[resources] and [webapp] folders.
inside [webapp] there is index.jsp and [WEB-INF].
inside [WEB-INF] there is web.xml and [jsp] folder.

```
[target]
.classpath
.project
pom.xml
```

I did :
File --> Import --> Existing Maven projects

The project now appear in Project Explorer of Eclipse with this contents :

```
src/main/java
src/main/resources
src/test/java
JRE System Library[JavaSE-1.6]
Maven Dependencies
bin
src
target
pom.xm
```

My question, where are :
WEB-INF and jsps ?

Thanks, your help is appreciated.
John

Answer (score 1):

Down below the source files that you described, you should see a "src" folder (with nothing after it). Drill into this folder and you should find your missing files.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run mvn eclipse:eclipse?

Comment: No I did not, after checking the project out I omported it in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you will need to make sure you have the Eclipse Maven Plugin installed. You can get it [here](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/). Once thats there, you will need to run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` on the project base folder on command line. That will create `.project`, `.settings` and `.classpath` files, making it a valid Eclipse project. Now start Eclipse, select `File -> Import -> Existing Projects in Workspace` and navigate to the project folder. You should be able to see the project with Maven folder layout now.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) plugin to work on maven projects in eclipse.  Assuming you have installed this and m2eclipse extras (for WTP support), import the project in eclipse as a maven project.  The jsps should be show up in `Web Resources (src/main/webapp)`.

Note that this plugin does not need you to run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` either. If you have done this and want to undo it, you can run `mvn eclipse:clean`.

Comment: This is where I got the project :
To download the Eclipse project for this application, please click :

http://www.box.net/shared/9n91enxho1

Please show me the steps to run this project in eclipse.

Thanks.